# add multiple custom attributes to datatables row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table created in DataTables 1.10:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable( {    
      "data" : dataSet,                      
      "bInfo": false,
      "bFilter" : false,
      paging: false,
      "createdRow" : function (row,data,index) {      
      $('td',row).eq(0).attr('id', 'cost-' + index);
      $('td',row).eq(1).attr('id', 'resale-' + index);

      deleteImage = $('<img />').attr('src', '../../img/details_close.png');           
      $('td',row).eq(0).append(deleteImage);      
      $('td',row).eq(0).addClass( 'icons' );

    },
      "columns" : [        
        { title : 'Cost' },
        { title : 'Resale' },        
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
    { className: "details-control", "targets": [ 0 ] }
    ]

  });
```

This works fine.  I am trying to add an image to the first `<td>` using the following code:

```
      deleteImage = $('<img />').attr('src', '../../img/details_close.png');           
      $('td',row).eq(0).append(deleteImage);      
      $('td',row).eq(0).addClass( 'icons' );
```

This also works fine.  It adds the image, and adds a class to the particular `<td>`.

My issue is that I also want to add an `id` to this image so I can call an `click event` using Javascript, but all of my attempts so far have not worked, including:

```
deleteImage = $('<img />').attr('src', '../../img/details_close.png', 'id','deleteLine');
```

and

```
deleteImage = $('<img />').attr('src', '../../img/details_close.png');       
      deleteID = $('<img />').attr('id', 'deleteLine');
      $('td',row).eq(0).append(deleteImage);      
      $('td',row).eq(0).append(deleteID);
```

(this second one does add `<img id="deleteLine">` to my page, but it's separate from the image that was inserted with `$('td',row).eq(0).append(deleteImage);`, so that doesn't help me.)

I just can't figure out the exact syntax to get this to work.....

Comment: My approach works just fine..........  Btw, here's how to do it in case anyone else comes across the same question and actually wants an answer instead of a critique:  `deleteImage = $('<img />').attr({ src:'../../img/details_close.png',id:'deleteLine'});`  Wrap the various elements you're trying to add in `{ }`.

Comment: Please add it as an answer to close the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it in case anyone else comes across the same question:

```
deleteImage = $('<img />').attr({ src:'../../img/details_close.png',id:'deleteLine'});
```

Just wrap the various elements you're trying to add in { }, separated each by a comma.